# Range of convergence for Taylor's series (about 0) for e^(sin x)

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Is there anything wrong with my method below? Also, is there an easier method?

For $sin\,x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}$,

$L_1 = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{x^{1+2(k+1)}}{(1+2(k+1))!} 
\div \frac{x^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}\right|$

$= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{x^2}{(2k+3)(2k+2)} \right| = 0 < 1 \;\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

Thus, by ratio test, $sin\,x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}$ converges $\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

Next, for $e^{sin\,x}= 1 + \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{sin^k x}{k!}$,

$L_2 = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{sin^{k+1}x}{(k+1)!} \div \frac{sin^k x}{k!}\right|$

$= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{sin\,x}{k+1} \right|$

$= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}}{k+1} \right| = 0 < 1 \;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

since $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}$ converges $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Thus, by ratio test, the Taylor's series (about 0) of $e^{sin\,x}$ converges $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with what you've written.

I wouldn't say it was necessary to sub back in the taylor series for $\sin{x}$ three lines from the bottom. I'm not sure you need to use the taylor series for $\sin$ explicitly anyway. You could either note that

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\:\mid \sin{x}\mid\; \leq 1$

and then put that into your limit and have $L_2\leq0$, hence $L_2=0$.

Or just use that sin x is constant w.r.t. the limit being taken and take it outside the limit.

$L_2= \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{\sin x}{k+1} \right|=\left| \sin x \right|\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}=0$.

I suppose this holds whenever $\sin$ is well defined, which is everywhere.

Comment: Hi, @snulty,

Thanks. Correct me if I am wrong but...

$\left| sin\,x \right| \leq 1 $ does not imply the Taylor's series for $sin\,x$ converges, does it?

If the Taylor's series for $sin\,x$ does not converge, then the Taylor's series for $e^{sin\,x}$ does not converge, right?

In other words, 

if $sin\,x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}$ does not converge, 

then it may be unbounded and

then 

$L_2 = \left| sin\,x \right|\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{1}{k+1} \right|$ is not equal to 0, right?

Comment: @Neo No you're right it doesn't imply convergence of a taylor series. I mean you could take a bounded non-analytic function, which wouldn't have a taylor series even in which case boundedness has no impact. The point I was trying to convey was using the taylor series of $\sin$ isn't really necessary. I mean if you're dealing with power series generally, just because the power series doesn't converge doesn't mean the function doesn't have a value there or is not finite there, e.g. $\frac{1}{1-x}\equiv\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$ provided $\mid x\mid<1$. The series diverges at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @Neo Just the continue, the series diverges at both $\pm1$, (and at any point of magnitude bigger than 1), but the function has a pole at $x=+1$, and equals $1/2$ at $x=-1$. The reason for the finite radius of convergence is due to a singularity at $x=1$, and there is a theorem in complex analysis that says that a function with a finite radius of convergence has at least one singularity on the "circle of convergence". Anyway resorting to a taylor series (not in the case of $\sin$) might be limiting.

Comment: @Neo Finally, just to re-emphasize, I *didn't* have a problem with your method in terms of it's *correctness*, but maybe someone else can post a comment/reply on your post, and possibly what I've said. Hope I'm being helpful though in some way :)

Comment: Thanks, @snulty. =) You taught me a few points and have definitely been helpful. Otherwise, I am still stuck and won't know what else I should consider.