# Compostion of functions in taylor series

Tags: analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, function-and-relation-composition

I was attempting to help answer a question, but I am curious about the following.

Suppose we have an analytic function $f(z)\equiv\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k(z-z_0)^k $ on some suitable disk of convergence in $\mathbb{C}$, if $g(z)$ is some other function, when is the taylor series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k(g(z)-z_0)^k $ equal to $f(g(z))$?

The example I was attempting to address was the radius of convergence in the real taylor series in the following question:

[Range of convergence for Taylor's series (about 0) for e^(sin x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759119/range-of-convergence-for-taylors-series-about-0-for-esin-x/759196#759196)

but another one I am curious is the following:

$e^z\equiv\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

The exponential function is entire. But suppose we compose with another function e.g. going back to $\mathbb{R}$ with the $\mid x\mid$ function, we could sub in to the taylor series about and get the following series:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mid x\mid^n}{n!}$

but would this converge to $e^{\mid x\mid}$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I expect it would but it shouldn't be a taylor series for the function $e^{\mid x\mid}$, because it isn't analytic at $x=0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z$ in some set of complex numbers, you can substitute any expression $w$ for $z$, and the equation $f(w) = g(w)$ will still be true as long as
$w$ is in that same set.  There's nothing special about series here.